# AWS, Django, Apache, ALLOWED_HOSTS not working 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services

I have two Django applications working on the AWS Lightsail. First one is working great with `www.firstapp.com` and `firstapp.com`, but when I try to visit the second app without `www` in URL, it returns 400 Bad Request. In both apps, `DEBUG` set to `False`, and I have necessary hosts in `settings.py` like this:

```
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        '.secondapp.com'
    ]
```

I have tried with `'*'` and also tried to write down all possible hosts in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but it didn't work. I am able to see website with `www.secondapp.com` but `secondapp.com` always return `Bad Request (400)`

After any update in `settings.py`, I always restart Apache (tried to reload also) nothing changes, still getting 400 Bad Request. Any ideas? Maybe I should set up AWS in some way, this is my first experience with Django

Comment: Not only Apache, you also need to restart the Gunicorn process so the changes in the `settings.py` file take effect

Comment: @VitorFreitas I don't use gunicorn

Comment: have you checked if you have more than one `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in the same `settings.py` file? One could be overriding the other.

Comment: Yes sure, I have only one

Comment: You should provide your apache configuration.

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved it. @AshishNitinPatil yes it was in my apache configurations, I have `ServerName` as `www.secondapp.com` when I add ServerAlias `secondapp.com` it works. Strange thing that I don't have ServerAlias for first application but it still working as `www.firstapp.com` and `firstapp.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who will face this kind of issues, check your VirtualHost configurations. In my VirtualHost configurations I had `ServerName` as `www.secondapp.com` when I add ServerAlias `secondapp.com` it works. Now I am able to see my app with `www.secondapp.com` and `secondapp.com`.

P.S.: However I don't have ServerAlias for first application but it still working as `www.firstapp.com` and `firstapp.com`, not sure why this casing an issue for the second one.